# Upgrade or install Ghostscript 9.21 in docker image node:7

Tags: node.js, docker, ghostscript

I'm installing Ghostscript into a docker image and want to use it with ghostscript4js which requires for some functionality at least Ghostscript 9.21.

I'm using this in my docker file which installs Ghostscript 9.06

```
    FROM node:7

ARG JOB_TOKEN

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y pdftk

ENV APP_DIR="/usr/src/app" \
    JOB_TOKEN=${JOB_TOKEN} \
    APP_DIR="/usr/src/app" \
    GS4JS_HOME="/usr/lib"


COPY ./ ${APP_DIR}

# Step 1: Install App
# -------------------
WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}

# Step 2: Install Python, GhostScript and npm packages
# -------------------
ARG CACHE_DATE=2017-01-01
RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y build-essential make gcc g++ python python-dev python-pip python-virtualenv && \
  apt-get -y install ghostscript && apt-get clean && \
  apt-get install -y libgs-dev && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


RUN npm install

# Step 3: Start App
# -----------------
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

How do I install or upgrade to a higher Ghostscript version in a docker image?

Comment: Did you rebuild your image already so the latest ghostscript binaries will be installed? `docker build  --no-cache -t my-image .`

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the distro you are using (since you use apt-get) is only on 9.06. Not surprising, many distros remain behind the curve, especially long term support ones.

If you want to use a more recent version of Ghostscript, then you could nag the packager to update. And you know, 9.06 is 5 years old now.....

Failing that you'll have to build it yourself. Git clone the Ghostscript repository, cd ghostpdl, ./autogen.sh, make install. That of course gets the current bleeding edge source, for a release version you'll have to pull from one of the tags (we tag the source for each release).

Or build it yourself locally and put it somewhere that your docker image can retrieve it from.

IMO if you are going to use a version other than the one provided by the packager of your distro, you may as well use the current release. That's currently 9.22 and will be 9.23 in a few weeks.